# Connection refused on ajax api request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application which is trying to sent an ajax request to an external api, the request returns with a connection refused error on console. Below is the code I am using along with the image of the actual issue. Any suggestions on this ? or if someone can point me in the right direction, thanks.

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: "POST",
   data: args,
   timeout: 15000,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (err) {
      console.dir(err);
   }
});
```

[Console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meLbD.png)